# UITableView - scroll to the top

Tags: ios, uitableview

In my table view I have to scroll to the top. But I cannot guarantee that the first object is going to be section 0, row 0. May be that my table view will start from section number 5.

So I get an exception, when I call:

```
[mainTableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];
```

Is there another way to scroll to the top of table view?

Answer (score 907, accepted):

UITableView is a subclass of UIScrollView, so you can also use:

```
[mainTableView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1) animated:YES];
```

Or

```
[mainTableView setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:YES];
```

And in Swift:

```
mainTableView.setContentOffset(CGPointZero, animated:true)
```

And in Swift 3 & above:

```
mainTableView.setContentOffset(.zero, animated: true)
```

Comment: Worked for me too, even with a tableHeaderView

Comment: thanks. I just added that to my 'scrollToRowAtIndexPath' line and scrolling works fine now.

Comment: I first tried this with CGRectZero, which is equivalent to CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0). This does not work, but oddly the above does. I guess it needs a positive width and height. Thank you.

Comment: Using this code to go at some uiview in scroll: [scrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, yourview.frame.origin.y, 1, 1) animated:YES];

Comment: Note, you will want **animated:NO** if you run this in scrollToRowAtIndexPath: so as to make the table start in the correct position. Hope it helps!

Comment: @hasan83 CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0) or CGRectZero isn't a visible rect. I would also say that [mainTableView setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:YES]; is the prettier expression.

Comment: I tried this solution in xcode 6 + swift. not really working. any possible reason where I am wrong or why this is not working any more?

Comment: @JunchaoGu some code example would help. Should work in swift.

Comment: the code sample is too long to post here but basically I am calling a function from viewWillAppear, if some condition is met, I will be scrolling the table view to the top and insert some rows with UIView.animation. The solution from fabb worked but this one did not really scroll

Comment: @JunchaoGu can  only suggest to create a stackexchange question with some of the code and maybe a video showing the scroll problem...

Comment: `mainTableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint.zero, animated:true)` is more "swifty".

Comment: This didn't work for me in a table with multiple sections, each with a header. I had to use tableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0), at: .top, animated: false)

Comment: This worked fine for me (Swift 3, XCode 8), but only after I remembered to call `endRefreshing()` before since my UITableView contains an UIRefreshControl.

Comment: anyone noticed that in iOS11 this all is broken and not scrolling correctly in some cases?

Comment: @PeterLapisu `self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0), at: UITableViewScrollPosition.top, animated: true)` seems to work in iOS 11

Comment: nope, i tested this too, and all other methods to scroll

Comment: @PeterLapisu I'm getting the same problem, after switching ViewController via TabBar every answer in this page stop working, did you manage to resolve the issue?

Comment: @PeterLapisu For iOS 11 or later, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/48315689/1226963

Comment: the answer is correct but it may not work sometimes unless you enclose that code inside tableView.beginUpdates() and tableView.endUpdates(). After this my scroll always works.

Answer (score 250):

**Note**: This answer isn't valid for iOS 11 and later.

I prefer

```
[mainTableView setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:YES];
```

If you have a top inset on your table view, you have to subtract it:

```
[mainTableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0.0f, -mainTableView.contentInset.top) animated:YES];
```

Comment: Tomato, tomato. Hmm... That doesn't come across very clearly in writing.

Comment: This is the best way to use when you have table header or footer views and want them to be included too.

Comment: This is indeed a clear code, but it does not work when your `tableView` has non-zero `contentInset` from the top. For example: `tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(5.0f, 0.0f, 250.0f, 0.0f);`. If that is the case, in your code the `tableView` scrolls to `(0.0f, 5.0f)`.

Comment: The solution to my previous comment: `[tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0.0f, -tableView.contentInset.top) animated:YES];`

Comment: This is what I tried first. Strangely it didn't work, which is what sent me here. `scrollRectToVisible` does work.

Comment: tried catlan's answer but that one did not work. this answer worked well :P

Comment: On iOS 11 you should consider using `-scrollView.adjustedContentInset.top` instead.

Answer (score 89):

**Possible Actions:**

1

```
func scrollToFirstRow() {
    let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)
    self.tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, atScrollPosition: .Top, animated: true)
}
```

2

```
func scrollToLastRow() {
    let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: objects.count - 1, inSection: 0)
    self.tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, atScrollPosition: .Bottom, animated: true)
}
```

3

```
func scrollToSelectedRow() {
    let selectedRows = self.tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows
    if let selectedRow = selectedRows?[0] as? NSIndexPath {
        self.tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(selectedRow, atScrollPosition: .Middle, animated: true)
    }
}
```

4

```
func scrollToHeader() {
    self.tableView.scrollRectToVisible(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 1), animated: true)
}
```

5

```
func scrollToTop(){
    self.tableView.setContentOffset(CGPointMake(0,  UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarFrame.height ), animated: true)
}
```

Disable Scroll To Top:

```
func disableScrollsToTopPropertyOnAllSubviewsOf(view: UIView) {
    for subview in view.subviews {
        if let scrollView = subview as? UIScrollView {
            (scrollView as UIScrollView).scrollsToTop = false
        }
        self.disableScrollsToTopPropertyOnAllSubviewsOf(subview as UIView)
    }
}
```

Modify and use it as per requirement.

**Swift 4**

```
  func scrollToFirstRow() {
    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
    self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .top, animated: true)
  }
```

Comment: Thats the solution, perfect - scrollToFirstRow

Comment: Excellent summary. When you have section headers you'll have to use option4 scrollToHeader.

Comment: Is there a way to scroll up to a searchbar that is above the Tableview?

Comment: self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: at: animated:) worked perfectly for Swift 5.8!

Answer (score 27):

It's better to not use NSIndexPath (empty table), nor assume that top point is CGPointZero (content insets), that's what I use -

```
[tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0.0f, -tableView.contentInset.top) animated:YES];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: No longer valid as of iOS 11.

Answer (score 23):

**Swift 4**:

This works very well:

```
//self.tableView.reloadData() if you want to use this line remember to put it before 
let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .top, animated: true)
```

Comment: Not if you have a tableHeaderView in your tableView and it's inline (scrolls with the content)

Comment: I have both a plain and a `UITableViewStyleGrouped` (headers scrolls with the contents) and this code works. Be sure you are in the main thread and you launch this code after the view appear (`viewDidAppear`).  If you still have problems try to put the code inside this: `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+0.1, execute: { // the code }`

Comment: Thank you. It will get you to the first cell. However, it doesn't show the table view header.

Comment: This will fail if the tableView is empty for some reason (no cell in 0 section at 0 row)

Answer (score 23):

On iOS 11, use `adjustedContentInset` to correctly scroll to top for both cases when the in-call status bar is visible or not.

```
if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
    [tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, -tableView.adjustedContentInset.top) animated:YES];
} else {
    [tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, -tableView.contentInset.top) animated:YES];
}
```

Swift:

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: -tableView.adjustedContentInset.top), animated: true)
} else {
    tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: -tableView.contentInset.top), animated: true)
}
```

Comment: It may not work sometimes unless you enclose that code inside tableView.beginUpdates() and tableView.endUpdates(). After this my scroll always works.

Answer (score 22):

**DONT USE**

```
 tableView.setContentOffset(.zero, animated: true)
```

It can sometimes set the offset improperly.  For example, in my case, the cell was actually slightly above the view with safe area insets.  Not good.

**INSTEAD USE**

```
 tableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0), at: .top, animated: true)
```

Comment: Perfect Solution.

Comment: Neither of these solutions are valid. The first doesn't work under iOS 11 or later. The second doesn't work if the table view has a table header or the first section has a section header unless you really do want the first row at the top and don't care about showing any headers.

Comment: @rmaddy what's the best solution?

Answer (score 19):

I've encountered an issue calling trying some of the methods on an empty `tableView`. Here's another option for Swift 4 that handles empty tableviews.

```
extension UITableView {
  func hasRowAtIndexPath(indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return indexPath.section < self.numberOfSections && indexPath.row < self.numberOfRows(inSection: indexPath.section)
  }

  func scrollToTop(animated: Bool) {
    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
    if self.hasRowAtIndexPath(indexPath: indexPath) {
      self.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .top, animated: animated)
    }
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
// from yourViewController or yourTableViewController
tableView.scrollToTop(animated: true)//or false
```

Comment: This doesn't account for any table header or section header.

Answer (score 12):

For tables that have a `contentInset`, setting the content offset to `CGPointZero` will not work. It'll scroll to the content top vs. scrolling to the table top.

Taking content inset into account produces this instead:

```
[tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, -tableView.contentInset.top) animated:NO];
```

Comment: Thank you, I kept setting it to CGPointZero and could not understand why this was happening.

Comment: No longer valid as of iOS 11.

Answer (score 10):

This code let's you scroll a specific section to top

```
CGRect cellRect = [tableinstance rectForSection:section];
CGPoint origin = [tableinstacne convertPoint:cellRect.origin 
                                    fromView:<tableistance>];
[tableinstance setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, origin.y)];
```

Comment: This was the simplest code and it worked OK. I actually putted CGPointMake(0.0f, 0.0f). Cheers!

Comment: This code is very useful to make the section scroll top

Answer (score 10):

**Swift 5, iOS 13**

I know this question already has a lot of answers but from my experience this method always works:

```
let last = IndexPath(row: someArray.count - 1, section: 0)
tableView.scrollToRow(at: last, at: .bottom, animated: true)
```

And this is especially true if you're working with animations (like keyboard) or certain async tasks—the other answers will often scroll to the *almost* bottom. If for some reason this doesn't get you all the way to the bottom, it's almost certainly because of a competing animation so the workaround is to dispatch this animation to the end of the main queue:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    let last = IndexPath(row: self.someArray.count - 1, section: 0)
    self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: last, at: .bottom, animated: true)
}
```

This may seem redundant since you're already on the main queue but it's not because it serializes the animations.

Comment: You also need to check if there is a section

Comment: This works as long as you don't have zero rows in your tableView.  Otherwise, I'd recommend using @catlan's answer

Comment: @craft if you have zero rows in your table then you shouldn't be attempting to scroll to the bottom anyway because it's already there.

Comment: @bsod Thanks for the reply. I actually do have a case where it's relevant. I'm scrolling back to the top with section headers but no rows. Also, I think the question is about `top` not `bottom`

Answer (score 8):

Swift:

```
tableView.setContentOffset(CGPointZero, animated: true)
```

Comment: No longer valid as of iOS 11.

Answer (score 8):

Swift 3

```
tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint.zero, animated: true)
```

if `tableView.setContentOffset` don't work.

Use:

```
tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint.zero, animated: true)
tableView.endUpdates()
```

Comment: This isn't valid for iOS 11 or later.

Comment: Kudos for mentioning beginUpdates() and endUpdates()

Answer (score 7):

Adding on to what's already been said, you can create a extension (Swift) or category (Objective C) to make this easier in the future:

Swift:

```
extension UITableView {
    func scrollToTop(animated: Bool) {
        setContentOffset(CGPointZero, animated: animated)
    }
}
```

Any time you want to scroll any given tableView to the top you can call the following code:

```
tableView.scrollToTop(animated: true)
```

Comment: No longer valid as of iOS 11.

Answer (score 7):

Since my `tableView` is full of all kinds of insets, this was the only thing that worked well:

Swift 3

```
if tableView.numberOfSections > 0 && tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: 0) > 0 {
  tableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0), at: .top, animated: true)
}
```

Swift 2

```
if tableView.numberOfSections > 0 && tableView.numberOfRowsInSection(0) > 0 {
  tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0), atScrollPosition: .Top, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: this was more useful to me

Comment: great answer, appreciate it

Answer (score 6):

I prefer the following, as it takes into account an inset. If there is no inset, it will still scroll to the top as the inset will be 0.

```
tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: -tableView.contentInset.top), animated: true)
```

Comment: No longer valid as of iOS 11.

Answer (score 6):

In Swift 5 , Thanks @Adrian's answer a lot

```
extension UITableView{

    func hasRowAtIndexPath(indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return indexPath.section < numberOfSections && indexPath.row < numberOfRows(inSection: indexPath.section)
    }

    func scrollToTop(_ animated: Bool = false) {
        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
        if hasRowAtIndexPath(indexPath: indexPath) {
            scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .top, animated: animated)
        }
    }

}
```

Usage:

```
tableView.scrollToTop()
```

Comment: 1. This is also valid in Swift 4. 2. This doesn't work if there is a table header or a section header.

Answer (score 5):

Swift :

if you don't have tableView header :

```
tableView.setContentOffset(CGPointMake(0,  UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarFrame.height ), animated: true)
```

if so :

```
tableView.setContentOffset(CGPointMake(0, -tableViewheader.frame.height   + UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarFrame.height ), animated: true)
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's what I use to work correctly on iOS 11:

```
extension UIScrollView {
    func scrollToTop(animated: Bool) {
        var offset = contentOffset
        if #available(iOS 11, *) {
            offset.y = -adjustedContentInset.top
        } else {
            offset.y = -contentInset.top
        }
        setContentOffset(offset, animated: animated)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

using contentOffset is not the right way. this would be better as it is table view's natural way

```
tableView.scrollToRow(at: NSIndexPath.init(row: 0, section: 0) as IndexPath, at: .top, animated: true)
```

Comment: This won't work if there is a table header or a section header.

Answer (score 3):

This was the only code snippet that worked for me

Swift 4:

```
    tableView.scrollRectToVisible(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 1), animated: true)
    tableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0), at: .top, animated: true)
    tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: -70), animated: true)
```

P.S. 70 is the height of my header and table view cell

Comment: This is far from the correct way to scroll to the top. It makes no sense to use three separate lines just to set the content offset. Only the last line is needed but hardcoding a specific offset is not the correct solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
func scrollToTop() {
        NSIndexPath *topItem = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:0];
        [tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:topItem atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
}
```

call this function wherever you want UITableView scroll to top

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 4** via extension, handles empty table view:

```
extension UITableView {
    func scrollToTop(animated: Bool) {
        self.setContentOffset(CGPoint.zero, animated: animated);
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't valid as of iOS 11.

Answer (score 2):

I use tabBarController and i have a few section in my tableview at every tab, so this is best solution for me.

```
extension UITableView {

    func scrollToTop(){

        for index in 0...numberOfSections - 1 {
            if numberOfSections > 0 && numberOfRows(inSection: index) > 0 {
                scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: index), at: .top, animated: true)
                break
            }

            if index == numberOfSections - 1 {
                setContentOffset(.zero, animated: true)
                break
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

in swift

your row = selectioncellRowNumber
your section if you have = selectionNumber if you dont have set is to zero

//UITableViewScrollPosition.Middle or Bottom or Top

```
var lastIndex = NSIndexPath(forRow:  selectioncellRowNumber, inSection: selectionNumber)
self.tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(lastIndex, atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.Middle, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to add the multiply by `-1 *` to the sum of the status bar and the navigation bar, because it was going that height off the screen,

```
self.tableView.setContentOffset(CGPointMake(0 , -1 * 
  (self.navigationController!.navigationBar.height +  
  UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarFrame.height) ), animated:true)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here Is The Code To ScrollTableView To Top Programatically

Swift:

```
self.TableView.setContentOffset(CGPointMake(0, 1), animated:true)
```

Answer (score 1):

In Swift-3 :

```
self.tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint.zero, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need use Objective-C or you still in love:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
    [_tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution with scrollToRow which fixes the problem for empty TableView (needs for search).

```
import UIKit

extension UITableView {
    
    public func scrollToTop(animated: Bool = false) {
        if numberOfRows(inSection: 0) > 0 {
            scrollToRow(
                at: .init(row: 0, section: 0),
                at: .top,
                animated: animated
            )
        }
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way that I found to force `UITableViewController` to scroll-to-the-top under iPhone, iPad and macCatalyst (macOS) is as follows:

- prepare to return `0` from `[tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]`
- call `[self.tableView reloadData]`
- call `[self.tableView layoutIfNeeded]`
- prepare to return the factual row count from `[tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]`
- call `[self.tableView reloadData]`

Answer (score 0):

If you i would like move scroll animation in the table, use this code. The scroll move to top with animation in .5 seconds.

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];

[_tableContent scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1) animated:YES];

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Answer (score 0):

To have a completion when finished, add this extension

```
// MARK: - UIScrollView

extension UIScrollView {

    /// Animate scroll to top with completion
    ///
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - duration:   TimeInterval
    ///   - completion: Completion block
    func animateScrollToTop(withDuration duration:  TimeInterval,
                            completion:             @escaping (()->())) {

        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, animations: { [weak self] in
                self?.setContentOffset(CGPoint.zero, animated: false)
            }, completion: { finish in
                guard finish else {
                    return
                }
                completion()
        })
    }
}

tableView.animateScrollToTop(withDuration: 0.25) { 
    // Finish
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example of UIScrollView extension that you can use everywhere in your app.

1) First you should create `enum` with possible scroll directions:

```
enum ScrollDirection {
    case top, right, bottom, left

    func contentOffsetWith(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) -> CGPoint {
        var contentOffset = CGPoint.zero
        switch self {
            case .top:
                contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -scrollView.contentInset.top)
            case .right:
                contentOffset = CGPoint(x: scrollView.contentSize.width - scrollView.bounds.size.width, y: 0)
            case .bottom:
                contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.bounds.size.height)
            case .left:
                contentOffset = CGPoint(x: -scrollView.contentInset.left, y: 0)
            }
        return contentOffset
    }
}
```

2) Then add extension to UIScrollView:

```
extension UIScrollView {
    func scrollTo(direction: ScrollDirection, animated: Bool = true) {
        self.setContentOffset(direction.contentOffsetWith(self), animated: animated)
    }
}
```

3) Thats it! Now you can use it:

```
myScrollView.scrollTo(.top, animated: false)
```

This scroll bind to the tableView's content size and it looks more natural than scroll to `CGPoint.zero`

Answer (score -1):

With Swift:

```
self.scripSearchView.quickListTbl?.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, atScrollPosition: .Top, animated: true)
```

Answer (score -3):

Use this code for `UITableview` implementation in swift:

```
var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(“cell”)
if cell == nil {
    cell = UITableViewCell(style: .Value1, reuseIdentifier: “cell”)
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: The question was how to scroll UITableView to top. This post does not answer the question.

Answer (score -31):

If you don't want scrolling, you can start and stop the scrolling animation as soon as you start it.

```
    $('document').ready(function() {
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 500);
    return true;
    });
```

Also, to animate put values for 'x' and 'y', passing in 0,0 will scroll the page to the top left instantly.

```
window.scrollTo(x, y);
```

Comment: Hahahahhahaha this made me laugh for the first time today! :D