# Getting "No room is available to display rows" when setting gridView.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, .net-2.0

```
gridView.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = gridView.SelectedRows[0].Index;
```

blowing up with:

> No room is available to display rows

DataGridView is customized control in the unbound mode. datagridview.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex is not set in a specific datagridview based event.

Rows are added to the datagridview via gatagridview.Rows.Add method on DataSet.EndMerge then cells are styled and formatted row by row. Last selected row is cleared and restored and scroll bar position restored to the first visible row.

Trying find out what this exception actually means.

```
if (gridView.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    gridView.ClearSelection();

    T value = GetItemByRow(gridView.Rows[0]);

    bool isVisible = filter.ShouldShow(value);
    gridView.Rows[0].Selected = true;

    if (!isVisible)
    {
        gridView.Rows[0].Visible = true;
        gridView.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = gridView.SelectedRows[0].Index; 
        gridView.Rows[0].Visible = false;
    }
    else
    {
        gridView.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = gridView.SelectedRows[0].Index;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where in your code are you calling this?

Comment: After data is inserted into the datagridview

Comment: Not enough information.  Show your code.

Comment: Getting an exception in the else

Comment: What event are you running this code in?

Comment: I still don't know where you are running this code.  Constructor?  Form's load event?  Does `gridView.First....Index = 0;` work?  It would accomplish the same thing.  What you have posted does not reproduce the problem.

Comment: Running this code on a separate thread on dataset.endmerge event.

Comment: `gridView.First....Index = 0;`     
will not work all the time as some of the rows could be invisible that is why there is an if statement

Comment: You can't interact with GUI controls from a non-UI thread.

Comment: Code has been running for a while. This exception is thrown occasionally. No description of this exception online.

Comment: It's very unclear how any of that code works if it's running in a separate thread.

Comment: Have you seen this exception before?

Comment: Just [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0a0dbec1-5dc5-47fe-bf07-ee82fb4e621d/no-room-is-available-to-display-rows) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1331000/719186).  You would have to post code that reproduces the error.  It sounds like your threading code is severely borked.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When are row is present in the grid but not visible setting it to be first row will make it throw this exception.

Answer (score 1):

When the grid is automatically sized to be 0 height (or probably width) and you set

```
dataGridView.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = 0;
```

the exception will be thrown. Our grid has set `Dock = Fill` and in some cases was sized to be invisible.

Our fix was to set a MinimumSize to 100/50, and we never saw the exception again. Even if the grid is not within the window (and thus invisible) the exception will now not be thrown.

Comment: Worked for me on this error too. It makes sense.