# Tap TabBarItem to scrollToTop

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller, scrolltop

How can it be done ?

I tried everything I could find on stack overflow and nothing worked for me. I would like a solution that will work like Instagram. If you scrolled down tap the `TabBarItem` to go to the top .( I generally  use `tableviewControllers` and not view controllers if that matters the code)

Any help will be appreciated

In swift 2.2 thank you!

## What i tried:

```
//Using the UiTabBarDelegate
class BarsViewController: UITableViewController,UISearchResultsUpdating,UISearchBarDelegate,UISearchDisplayDelegate,UITabBarControllerDelegate,UITabBarDelegate{

    func tabBar(tabBar: UITabBar, didSelectItem item: UITabBarItem) {
            if(item.tag == 1) {
                //your code for tab item 1
                
            tableView.scrollToTop(true)
            
            }
            else if(item.tag == 2) {
                //your code for tab item 2
            }
            else if(item.tag == 4) {
                //your code for tab item 4
                self.tabBarItem.badgeValue = nil
                
                tableView.scrollToTop(true)        }
        }
    }
    
    extension UITableView {
        func scrollToTop(animated: Bool) {
            setContentOffset(CGPoint.zero, animated: animated)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your button action, call `tableView.scrollToRow(IndexPath(row: 0, section:0), at scrollPosition: .top, animated: true)`

Comment: i had to fix he line to this : `tableView.scrollToRow(NSIndexPath(row: 0, section:0), at, scrollPosition: .top, animated: true)` and i get an error `use of unresolved identifier 'at'`

Comment: Yes, you added an extra comma after "at". My code is in swift 3, so you'll need to change it if you're on an older version.

Answer (score 0):

Select your `tableView` and look at the `attributes inspector` on the right and make sure `scrollsToTop` is selected or try `self.yourTableView.scrollsToTop = true`

If you want to scroll to top on an action create an extension like this,

```
extension UITableView {
func scrollToTop(animated: Bool) {
    setContentOffset(CGPoint.zero, animated: animated)
 }
}
```

then in the `tabbar` or `button` call the function like this,

```
tableView.scrollToTop(animated: true)
```

This is in swift 3 but I received the info from this answer and was written in an earlier version of swift,
[scroll to top of tableView](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32443510/7657353)

Comment: Doesn't work i want when i scrolled down i press the tabbarbutton and it will scroll back up

Comment: I will look into it but you are talking about the statusbar not a tabbar right?

Comment: im talking about the tabbar.I want when im scrolled down in my tableviewcontroller i will press the current tabbarbutton that is selected and it will scroll to the top exactly what happens when you tap the status bar but if you press the current barbuttonitem... you got it?

Comment: Cool.I will try it in the upcoming weekend as i just returned to the army.

Comment: No @K-2SO it didnt

Comment: you set your delegates and all that stuff in your viewcontroller right? TableView and Tabbar?

Comment: Yea i did@K-2SO