# UITableView, UICollectionView scroll to top

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

UITableView and UICollectionView is able to scroll to top when you tap on top of the screen. Am I able to call this action from code? Or is there any other way to scroll to top of UITableView / UICollectionView?

I tried scrollToRow function, table scrolls to top, but navbar title remains small. I want to have it as big nav bar title like on load of viewController.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724892/uitableview-scroll-to-the-top Related?

Comment: Just set tableView/scrollView.setContentOffset(.zero, animated:true/false)

Comment: @Stiv there is same problem like with scrollToRow

Comment: @AhmadF I saw this post, but I did not find solution. With every try I still have problem like with scrollToRow.

Comment: You might need to treat it as a *scroll view* instead of a table view, don't scroll to a row, try to scroll to the top content size...

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
tableView.scrollView.scroll(to: .top)
collectionView.scrollView.scroll(to: .top)
```

...using the following extension that allows for several different scroll positions:

```
extension UIScrollView {
    enum Position {
        case top
        case center
        case bottom
    }
    /// Scrolls scroll view to y position passed, animated
    func scroll(to position: Position, animated: Bool = true) {
        switch position {
        case .top:
            self.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: -contentInset.top), animated: animated)
        case .center:
            self.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: contentSize.height/2-self.frame.height/2), animated: animated)
        case .bottom:
            self.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: contentSize.height-self.frame.height), animated: animated)
        }
    }
    /// Scrolls scroll view to y value passed, animated
    func scroll(to position: CGFloat, animated: Bool = true) {
        self.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: position), animated: animated)
    }

    /// Scrolls scroll view by y value passed, animated
    func scroll(by position: CGFloat, animated: Bool = true) {
        self.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.contentOffset.y + position), animated: animated)
    }

    func scroll(to view: UIView, animated: Bool = true) {
        self.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: view.frame.maxY), animated: animated)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use below line:

```
tableView.setContentOffset(.zero, animated: true)
```

Comment: same problem as with scrollToRow function