# iOS: Scroll UITableView back to the top after popping ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, tableview, popviewcontroller

My `UITableView` needs to scroll all the way to the top after popping back to `ViewController` under certain circumstances.

The code below works fine (I edited it for simplicity), but I am hoping to find a better way without using a delay timer. If I don't use a timer the `UITableView` doesn't scroll all the way to the top because the ViewController hasn't loaded yet (I think).

DetailController.m

```
- (void)popToViewController {
    // pop back to ViewController.
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    // Calls ViewController method
    [self.viewController method];
}
```

ViewController.m

```
- (void)method {
   dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 0.1 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:NO];
        });
}
```

I tried using `ViewDidAppear` in `ViewController` and it works, but it gets called all the time if I pop the ViewController. I only need to scroll the `UITableView` all the way up under certain circumstances.

Edit: I also tried `dispatch_async`, but it doesn't work all the time.

Comment: Use a delegate method going back from detailVC to masterVC. There you can pass a parameter with the conditions and then in masterVC you can decide to scroll or not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UITableView - scroll to the top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724892/uitableview-scroll-to-the-top)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to add a completion block for the animation. Remove your timer and try something like this:

```
- (void)popToViewController {
    [CATransaction begin];

    [CATransaction setCompletionBlock:^{
        [self.viewController method];
    }];

    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    [CATransaction commit];
}
```