# iOS tableView scrolls up even after contentoffset(0,0)

Tags: ios, contentoffset

In my app, I have a Table view with a search view of weight 197 above table cell.
There is a button for toggle search on pressing of which the content of table view needs to be offset accordingly. But I am not able to get the needed one. Here is the code snippet.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.tableShow.reloadData()
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.tableShow.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
}  

@IBAction func toggleSearch(_ sender: Any) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {

    if(self.searchView.isHidden){
        self.searchView.isHidden = false
    }
    else
    {
        self.searchView.isHidden = true
    }
    if (self.tableShow.contentOffset.y >= 197 ){

        self.tableShow.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        if !self.noRecordLabel.isHidden {
            self.noRecordLabel.isHidden = true
        }

    } else {

        self.tableShow.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 197                                     
        if self.jobsData.count == 0 {
            self.noRecordLabel.isHidden = false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724892/uitableview-scroll-to-the-top

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
tableShow.setContentOffset(CGPointZero, animated:true)
```

Comment: // , Why does this fix the issue?

Comment: This was included in viewdidAppear,but still the same issue.